# How do I utilize the features and keywords for rules in fapolicyd?

Tags: rhel, fapolicyd

I have an application a consultant is installing on our company machines.
We have recently upgraded our servers to RHEL 8 and have certain STIG compliance requirements to use fapolicyd.

Our new application isn't able to run because it is being blocked by fapolicyd.

I have attempted to create a rule to allow it to run. I have tried the following formats:

`allow perm=execute dir=/home/<app_name>/`

`allow perm=execute dir=/home/<app_name>/ : all`

`allow perm=execute dir=/home/<app_name>/ dir=/opt/<app_name_variant_versionNumber>/ dir=/opt/<app_name>/ : all`

`allow perm=execute exe=/home/<app_name>/ exe=/opt/<app_name_variant_versionNumber>/ exe=/opt/<app_name>/ : all`

`allow_audit perm=execute exe=/home/<app_name>/ exe=/opt/<app_name_variant_versionNumber>/ exe=/opt/<app_name>/ : all`

From what I glean from the man page exe= must have the full path to the actual executable, and dir has a few key words that can be used.

I think my solution lies with using dir with the keywords, but I haven't found an example anywhere as to how to apply those keywords.

**Does anyone have examples of how all the features and keywords work for rules in fapolicyd?**

Prior to my attempts this is what we gathered from a debug attempt:

```
rule=11 dec=deny_audit perm=open auid=-1 pid=702173 
exe=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.392.b08-4.el8.x86_64/jre/bin/java 
: path=/opt/<app_name_variant_versionNumber>/lib/launcher/groovy-3.0.7-indy.jar 
ftype=application/java-archive trust=0
```

**Have I mis-interpreted the blockage?**
**Should I be making a rule for java to access my app?**